# Oracle 18c - Left join conditional USING clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle18c

I have a cursor with a left join like so:

```
CURSOR c_emp
    SELECT * FROM FROM EMP_NEW
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EMP_ID,
            DEPT_ID,
            SUB_DEPT_ID,
            EMP_UID,
       FROM EMP)
       USING (DEPT_ID, SUB_DEPT_ID, EMP_UID);
```

Which is then referenced in a for loop:

```
For i in c_emp
IF i.emp_id IS NULL
then
    insert into emp...
else
    update emp...
    where emp_id = i.emp_id;
end if;
```

We have a scenario when loading new data into `EMP` table from the `EMP_NEW` table, the `emp_new.dept_id` and `emp_new.emp_uid` can have a duplicate in the `EMP` table with a different `sub_dept_id` value. When we get such new data, the `emp.emp_id` is not selected in the cursor, thus logic goes to `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`. I would like for the duplicate `emp_id` to be selected so it goes to the `UPDATE`.

EMP data:

```
EMP_ID     DEPT_ID     SUB_DEPT_ID      EMP_UID
123        1           10               123.123
```

EMP_NEW data:

```
DEPT_ID      SUB_DEPT_ID     EMP_UID
1            20              123.123
```

The above cursor currently returns the following:

```
EMP_ID     DEPT_ID     SUB_DEPT_ID      EMP_UID
null       1           20               123.123
```

What I would like it to return:

```
EMP_ID     DEPT_ID     SUB_DEPT_ID      EMP_UID
123        1           20               123.123
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: It seems `USING (DEPT_ID, EMP_UID)` must match your need.

Comment: Why can't you just remove sub_dept_id?

Comment: Please see added information

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to match on the 3 columns first and if not on just two columns.  I think a lateral join better fits your needs:

```
SELECT en.*, e.*
FROM EMP_NEW en LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT EMP_ID
      FROM EMP e
      WHERE en.DEPT_ID = e.DEPT_ID AND en.EMP_UID = e.EMP_UID
      ORDER BY (CASE WHEN en.SUB_DEPT_ID = e.SUB_DEPT_ID THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY  -- presumably you want only one row either way
     ) e
```

Comment: Thanks, however i've added more information to clarify the confusion. Please see edit.

Comment: @user3224907 . . . The above returns the version with the with same sub dept id first.  Just reverse the `order by` if you want the other one.

Comment: Could you please explain this logic `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN en.SUB_DEPT_ID = e.SUB_DEPT_ID THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)`

Comment: That chooses the row where the sub depts match as first.  I'm not sure if you want that first or last.

Comment: I thought you need to select at least 2 columns in the left join query if you want to `order by 2` ?

Comment: @user3224907 . . . Those are numbers, not column references.

Comment: Why did you remove the `USING` clause, isn't it required?

Comment: When I add `USING (DEPT_ID, SUB_DEPT_ID, EMP_UID)`, the `emp_id` is still `NULL`, causing the logic to go to the `INSERT`.

Comment: @user3224907 . . . There is no `using` clause with a lateral join.

Comment: I am getting `ORA-00905: missing keyword` without the `USING` CLAUSE

Comment: added some sample data if that helps.